# Is the normalized derivative of a holomorphic function Sobolev?

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, singularity-theory

This question is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205228/is-the-normalized-derivative-of-a-holomorphic-function-sobolev) from MSE. it is also a special case of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328348/is-polar-decomposition-of-a-smooth-map-sobolev).

Let $B=\{z\in \mathbb C \,|\,|z|\le 1\}$, and let $f:B \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on the interior $B^o$, and smooth on $B$.

> Suppose that $f'(z)$ is not identically zero. Are the **derivatives of** $\frac{f'(z)}{\|f'(z)\|}$ in $L^1(B)$?

More precisely, if $f=u+iv$, then $f'(z)=u_x+iv_x$, and I consider $$h(x,y)=\frac{u_x}{\sqrt{u_x^2+v_x^2}},g(x,y)=\frac{v_x}{\sqrt{u_x^2+v_x^2}}.$$

The question is whether or not $h_x,h_y,g_x,g_y \in L^1(B)$.

The assumption implies that $f'(z) \neq 0$ a.e. on $B$.

> For any $\epsilon >0$, the derivatives are integrable on $\{z\in \mathbb C:|z|\le 1-\epsilon\}$. The question is to determine what happens near the boundary.

Around any isolated zero of $f'$ in $B^o$, everything is fine*; $f'$ may vanish at infinitely many points (with an accumulation point on $\partial B$).

*Proof:

Suppose that $f'(0)=0$; write $f'(z)=z^ng(z)$ for some holomorphic $g$ satisfying $g(0) \neq 0$. Then $\frac{f'(z)}{\|f'(z)\|}=\frac{z^n}{\|z^n\|}\frac{g(z)}{\|g(z)\|}$. $g$ is smooth and non-zero around $z=0$, so the factor $\frac{g(z)}{\|g(z)\|}$ causes no problems. We are left with $\frac{z^n}{\|z^n\|}=(\frac{z}{\|z\|})^n=e^{in\theta}$, which reduces the problem to the analysis of the argument function $\theta$ (the case of $\frac{z}{\|z\|}$). What is left is a [straightforward calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192591/is-the-projection-onto-the-unit-circle-sobolev?noredirect=1&lq=1).

*Edit:*

[It seems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331335/is-the-normalized-derivative-of-a-holomorphic-function-sobolev#comment826262_331335) that there might be explosions near the boundary, even when $f'$ is never zero. So, I guess that the answer is negative?

Comment: You have enough trouble even without zeroes: just consider the function $f$ with the derivative $f'(z)=e^{-(1-z)^{-1/2}}e^{-\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$ (the first factor is there just to ensure $C^\infty$ up to the boundary).

Comment: I am probably missing something stupid, but: The normalized derivative is measurable and bounded, so it is surely in $L^1(B)$, assuming that you use the Lebesgue measure on $B$.

Comment: @Asaf: Right, I am stupid. Thanks for confirming :P

Comment: Around $1$, of course.

Comment: Yes, they diverge. The essential part iz $1/(1-z)^2$ near $1$. The first factor doesn't contribute much. If you still  have trouble seeing why, let me know and I'll post a detailed explanation when I have time.

Comment: "should be smooth on the entire closed disk" Why "closed"? There may be zeroes on the boundary, so you lose smoothness when you approach them.